# how to relate point in a map with a wifi signals strengths (android)

Tags: android, dictionary

I have the following code to display a map on screen:

```
package com.example.finalproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
     protected MapView mMap;
     protected String mSelectedMap; // id of the map which is currently being displayed

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMap = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMap.setOnTouchListener(this);
        this.setMap(R.drawable.discovery); // set map to default location (== first floor)

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void setMap(int resId) {
        mSelectedMap = String.valueOf(resId);
        mMap.setImageResource(resId); // change map image
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.onTouchEvent(event);

        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is to obtain wifi signals as follows:

```
mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

        List<ScanResult> wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
        ArrayList<WifiConnectionBean> m4MessagesList = new ArrayList<WifiConnectionBean>();
        for (int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++) {
            ScanResult scanResult = wifiList.get(i);
            WifiConnectionBean bean = new WifiConnectionBean();
            bean.setConnectionName(scanResult.SSID); // + "--" +
                                                        // scanResult.frequency);
            bean.setDescription(scanResult.capabilities);
            bean.setId(scanResult.SSID);
            bean.setLevel(String.valueOf(scanResult.level));
            bean.setSignalStrength(String.valueOf(scanResult.BSSID));
            m4MessagesList.add(bean);
        }
        if (m4MessagesList == null) {
            Toast.makeText(WifiIdentificationActivity.this,
                    "WifiConnection not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            String message = "Scanning complete. " + m4MessagesList.size()
                    + " connections found!";
        }
        pd.dismiss();

    }
}
```

and relate the readings of one scan to a point on a map.
that relation has to be stored in a database
any recommendations on a general way to implement it?

Comment: Do you mean to get the current position of the device via wifi signal strengths?

Comment: yes. the method is called wifi fingerprinting, I'm trying to get the offline phase running